# Joining two dataframes to plot a map with ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

I want to make a worldmap visualization using an data frame, which look like this:

```
Country Year    Sex         Age Suicides Population Suicides_per_100k Country_Year HDI/Year   Year_GDP
1 Albania 1987   Male 15-24 years       21     312900              6.71  Albania1987       NA 2156624900
2 Albania 1987   Male 35-54 years       16     308000              5.19  Albania1987       NA 2156624900
3 Albania 1987 Female 15-24 years       14     289700              4.83  Albania1987       NA 2156624900
4 Albania 1987   Male   75+ years        1      21800              4.59  Albania1987       NA 2156624900
5 Albania 1987   Male 25-34 years        9     274300              3.28  Albania1987       NA 2156624900
6 Albania 1987 Female   75+ years        1      35600              2.81  Albania1987       NA 2156624900
  GDP_Per_Capita      Generation Continent
1            796    Generation X    Europe
2            796          Silent    Europe
3            796    Generation X    Europe
4            796 G.I. Generation    Europe
5            796         Boomers    Europe
6            796 G.I. Generation    Europe
```

I tried to use the following code:

```
world <- ggplot2::map_data('world')
worldstart <- left_join(df,world,by = c("Country"="region")
```

This code created a new dataframe with 14 million observations.
But, I'd like to keep the same number of the dataset "df".
What is the best approach?

Comment: You have multiple values of `Country` in `df`, there are multiple values of `region` in `world`. Hence, when you `left_join` all combinations are generated for each country. Let's say there are 6 rows of "Albania" in `df` and 4 rows of "Albania" in `world` when you join them you'll get 24 rows. How will you keep same number of rows as `df` ? How will you decide to match which rows in `df` with which rows in `world` ?

Comment: True, but using this approach, they have multiple values of lat/long for each country, making the joined df huge

Answer (score 0):

Indeed, the map_data functions returns the values for each point of each multipolygons in the world (~10k rows). As mentioned earlier, you cannot chose what point to keep.

You can use the sf library to go around this difficulty, keeping the geometry (here multipolygons) on one side and your data on the other.

My proposal would be the following :

```
library(dplyr)
library(sf)
library(ggplot2)

df <- tibble(Country = "Albania", 
             GDP_per_Capita = 796)

world <- maps::map('world', plot = F, fill = T) %>% st_as_sf(stringsAsFactors = F)
world_df <- df %>% 
  left_join(world, by = c("Country" = "ID"))
```

In my example, you would have only one row of data, but the geometry columns contains all necessary information for plotting.

sf and ggplot2 are well linked so you are good to go.

Best regards